# If shared preferences does not contain

Tags: java, android

```
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue",0);

    if(mPrefs.contains("DATE")) {
    //do something
    }else {
        mPrefs.edit().putString("DATE", currentdate);
        mPrefs.edit().commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

What i want the code to do is run the first time and show the toast but the second time it is run not show it and run the code inside the first parameters. But as it is now the code just runs the second "else" statement twice and doesn't even run the first. it's as if the string isn't even being put in "DATE"? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Mate don't reedit, add the commit at the end of the first line  mPrefs.edit().putString("DATE", currentdate).commit();

Comment: thank you good sir, it worked but im not sure how. Isn't it the same?

Comment: No mate, you are opening it for edit, then without commiting (saving) you reopen for edit (so the first change wasn't saved).

Answer (score 0):

Make `Editor` Object and use it for edit/commit.

You can use below code. it will work fine.

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

if(mPrefs.contains("DATE")) {
            //do something
}else {
     mEditor.putString("DATE", currentdate);
     mEditor.commit();
     Toast.makeText(this, "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: contains of the op was fine. To improve i'd just set currentDate as defaultValue return when getting the mStringDate if he only wants to show a Toast for debug